# drawing a itinerary on maps using a linestring with openlayers 3

Tags: maps, drawing, openlayers

Im new on openlayers so i try to make a itinerary using tow point, i can draw  a line but not itinerary.

here is my code

```
var lineFeature = new ol.Feature(
new ol.geom.LineString([ol.proj.transform([4.658166 ,44.199790], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), ol.proj.transform([ 1.425145 , 43.340356 ],'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')])
);
var style = {
strokeColor: '#0000ff',
strokeOpacity: 0.5,
strokeWidth: 5
};
var vectorlinenew = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features:[ lineFeature ]
}),
name:'linefeature'
});
map.addLayer(vectorlinenew);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got your question right, but I believe it draws the line just because you passed just two points to `ol.geom.LineString` whereas it accepts multiple points and would draw the line over all of them. So all you have to do is just pass an array of all your points to `ol.geom.LineString` and it will draw the itinerary line.